# Partial Documentation

Tags: android-studio

I don't know why I don't have documentation for  FragmentManager IDE shows android.support.v4.app public abstract class FragmentManager
extends Object

Gradle: com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0@aar

but for example TextView IDE is fetching it and it works.

Why isn't Android studio downloading doc for FragmentManager?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google didn't add documentation in Android Studio for that. It's normal. I have to look for info about Fragments on android google site.